# Write data to an excel sheet on box folder using xlwings

Tags: python, excel

I would like to ask for your opinions and suggestions. Currently, I am writing or updating an excel sheet of an excel file saved on the box folder, however, using openpyxl, it affects the other features of the file such as graphs. Using xlwings, I can write data to it without affecting the file's features, but I was testing it locally. Is it possible to use xlwings to write data in excel saved on box folder? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

What is a "box" folder? A folder in the cloud? Of course there is a way, we just need many more specifics to understand what you are trying to do.

My "answer" would be to get the workbook, do what you need to, and then save it to the cloud folder.

Comment: Hi @Eric M. Yes, a folder in the cloud. However, it is common issue of openpyxl that sometimes it corrupts or remove some graphs or features of the existing xlsx file? Thank you!

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, I believe you can write to a cloud folder with xlwings. However I think there can be issues with it. So personally I would download the file from the cloud, modify it as needed, and then upload it back to the cloud.

Comment: Hi @Eric. Thank you for your opinion and advice! I appreciate it! I will use this as my reference for the future projects.